# Accessibility issue radio buttons

Tags: angularjs, accessibility, radio-group, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I'm using AngularJS and have a custom directive for radio buttons so they can be placed anywhere on the site. I'm doing some accessibility work as some of the radio buttons when using JAWS screen reader. The issue I'm having is this: When you tab to a certain radio button groups the radio button does show focus and the screen reader reads the radio button label. However in certain radio button groups the screen reader doesn't read *"do not prompt user to "to change the selection press the up or down arrow"* as it should. Other radio buttons on my site using this directive do not have this issue. In the instances where this issue occurs you cannot use the arrow keys to change the radio buttons as you can in the fully functioning radio button groups sharing the same directive. However, when you tab past these buggy radio button groups and then do a backwards tab (shift + tab) back the radio button group it functions as it should. It receives focus and the screen reader reads everything out as it should.

Comment: did you compare the generated html (code inspector) for the two radios?  the one that works and the one that doesn't?  can you post the generated code?  also, which screen readers and which browsers did you test it on?  jaws sometimes works differently on firefox and internet explorer and chrome.  and nvda and voiceover might be different from jaws.

Comment: I am having the same issue. My radio buttons group is in dialog box. When the dialog is opened I focus the first button. Then I am not able to navigate through the options with the arrows. The reader starts reading the labels of the buttons. Then I am able to select them with space but this is not the expected behaviour. When I navigate with tab to other element and then shift+tab to return the focus on the radio buttons the arrow navigation works fine. The most interesting thing is that it works correctly on chrome and firefox. The issue comes only when using IE. Without JAWS it work well too